# Using C# & SMO, how do I add a backup device to a SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I know how to use C# and SMO to create a file backup on a SQL Server:

```
public void BackupDatabase(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server, 
                               string databaseName, string backupFilename,
                               string backupName, string backupDescription) {

 Backup backup = new Backup();
 backup.Devices.AddDevice(backupFilename, DeviceType.File);
 backup.Database = databaseName;
 backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
 backup.BackupSetDescription = backupDescription;
 backup.BackupSetName = backupName;
 backup.Incremental = false;
 backup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
 backup.Initialize = true; // supposed to overwrite
 backup.SqlBackup(server);
}
```

What I don't know (and can't find) is how to add the file BackupDevice to the SQL server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [BackupDevice.Create](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backupdevice.create%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
Server server = new Server("localhost");
BackupDevice newDevice = new BackupDevice();
newDevice.Parent = server;
newDevice.Name = "newDevice";
newDevice.BackupDeviceType = BackupDeviceType.Disk;
newDevice.PhysicalLocation = "c:\temp\newdevice.bak";
newDevice.Create();
```

Comment: @remus-rusanu:  Thanks much!  I missed the .Create().

Comment: how to add date instead of name in c:\temp\newdevice.bak