# BackupDevice.PhysicalLocation does not add to specified location

Tags: c#, backup, smo

Using C# and SMO, when I create backups they are being copied to the default backup location used by SQL Server (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup), instead of the physical location that I specify in code:

```
 Database database = Server.Databases[dbName]);
  Backup backup = new Backup();

  device = new BackupDevice();
  device.Parent = Server;
  device.Name = dbName + ".bak";
  device.BackupDeviceType = BackupDeviceType.Disk;
  device.PhysicalLocation = Path.Combine(filePath + device.Name); // doesn't appear to do anything
  device.Create();

  backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
  backup.Database = database.Name;
  backup.Devices.AddDevice(filePath, DeviceType.File);
  backup.SqlBackup(server);
```

When I run my code, I find that the path that I specified ("C:\backupTest") is empty and the backup has been added to the default backup location.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Verify the Service has permissons to the location you specify.  Your code should work since its a nearly identical to the code located in this answer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472316/using-c-sharp-smo-how-do-i-add-a-backup-device-to-a-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: I added 'everyone' permission to my target folder and it still adds the backup to the default folder. Although wouldn't an Exception be thrown if it were a permissions issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below code

```
static void BackupDataBase(string databaseName, string destinationPath)
{
    try
    {
        Server myServer = GetServer();
        Backup backup = new Backup();
        backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        backup.Database = databaseName;
        destinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, databaseName + ".bak");
        backup.Devices.Add(new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File));
        backup.Initialize = true;
        backup.Checksum = true;
        backup.ContinueAfterError = true;
        backup.Incremental = false;
        backup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
        backup.SqlBackup(myServer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private static Server GetServer()
{
    ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection("server", "username", "pw");
    Server myServer = new Server(conn);
    return myServer;
}
```

refere [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26390/SQL-Server-2005-Database-Backup-and-Restore-using) codeproject article for more information.